# Show that $a\ |\ b \implies \varphi(a)\ |\ \varphi(b)$ from 2 properties

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$$ a \mid b \implies \varphi(a) \mid \varphi(b)$$

I need to deduce the above from:

(i) if $p$ is prime and $p\mid a$ then $\varphi(ap) = p\varphi(a)$.

(ii) if $p\nmid a$ then $\varphi(ap) = (p-1)\varphi(a)$.

I have proven (i) and (ii). But do not see how the deduce bit follows. Could someone provide a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking both cases together, you have $\phi(a)\mid\phi(pa)$. Now assume $a\mid b$. Then you can obtain $b$ from $a$ in finitely many steps where each consists in multiplying by a prime.

Comment: Not sure what you mean at the end. If $a\ |\ b$ then $b=na = p_1*\ldots*p_k*a$

Comment: @George Indeed, and we have $\phi(a)\mid\phi(p_1a)\mid\phi(p_1p_2a)\mid\cdots\mid \phi(p_1p_2\cdots p_ka)=\phi(b)$.